# How to prove that $(G, *)$ is a group when $G = \left \{0, \frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}, ..., \frac{n-1}{n} \right \}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics

Also the binary operator $*$, describes this behavior:

$$\frac{k}{n} * \frac{l}{n} = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{k+l}{n} & \text{whenever} & k+l < n\\ 
& & \\
\frac{k+l-n}{n} & \text{whenever} & k+l\geq n
\end{matrix}\right.$$

When I do the calculations I get 0 as the identity element but I can not find any inverses.

Comment: But is $n\in G$?

Comment: $\LaTeX \text{ Tip}:$ Use \text{whatever you choose} to obtain $\text{whatever you choose}$

Comment: Sure, $n\in\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, but is $n\in G$? As for $n$ to be an identity of $G$, surely it would need to be an element of $G$

Comment: Please insert the question (as a question) in the text, not in the title. If there are two or more questions in a row, please make this clear, so that an answerer can see them at once, and give a possibly full answer. It still remains the point that $n$ is not in the list of elements of $G$, not even $n/n=1$, which would have some chance when $n=1$.

Comment: but if $n=\pi,$ $n$ couldn't be in G?

Comment: You may need the restriction where $n\in(0,1)$?

Comment: OK, an edit was made, please make clear that $n$ is a natural number $>0$, or else give an explanation of $1,2,\dots,n-1$ :: What is that $n-1$ for an irrational / non integer $n$ after the dots?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to say $n \in \Bbb R$; surely $n$ must be an integer. For example, take $n = 10.5$. What does it mean to say $G = \left\{0, \frac1{10.5}, \frac2{10.5},\ldots,\frac{9.5}{10.5}\right\}$?

Comment: OK, there is a -1 from me as long as a negative $n$ is allowed.

Comment: This is my final comment, in case of an $n\in\Bbb Z_{>0}$ there is an obvious bijection of the set $G$ to the set underlying the group $(\Bbb Z/n, +)$, and the operation is transported from there, so that there correspond $k$ from $\Bbb Z$ modulo $n$, taken to be in the usual set of representatives $0,1,2,\dots,(n-1)$, to the $k/n\in G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{k}{n} * \frac{l}{n} = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{k+l}{n} & \text{whenever} & k+l < n\\ 
& & \\
\frac{k+l-n}{n} & \text{whenever} & k+l\geq n
\end{matrix}\right.$$

The identity is $0$ since $0=\frac{0}{n}$ and $\frac{0}{n}*\frac{l}{n} = \frac{0+l}{n}=\frac{l}{n}$ since $0+l<n$; in fact, $\frac{l}{n} *0=\frac{l}{n} $ since $+$ is commutative.

Given $\frac{l}{n} $ where $0\le l\le n-1$, we want to find an inverse $(\frac{l}{n} )^{-1}$.  That is, we want $p$ such that $\frac{l}{n} *\frac{p}{n}=0=\frac{p}{n}* \frac{l}{n}  $ but then clearly $p=n-l$ since 
$$\frac{l}{n} *\frac{n-l}{n} =\frac{l+(n-l)-n}{n} =\frac{0}{n}$$

since $l+(n-l)\ge n$, indeed  $\frac{n-l}{n} *\frac{l}{n}=0$ as well (since $+$ is commutative).

Lastly we prove closure.  If $k+l<n$ then $\frac{k}{n}*\frac{l}{n}=\frac{k+l}{n}$ and $0\ge k+l<n$ so that $\frac{k+l}{n}\in G$.  And if $k+l\ge n$ then because the maximum of these two is $n+n$ if we subtract $n$ from this under the second rule then $0\le k+l-n\le 2n - n= n$

Let me know if you need any further clarification!

Comment: I never knew Squirtle was an algebrist!?  What about Charazard?

Comment: Associativity? Has anyone the courage to try proving it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need more clarification on associativity. How can we prove that the operation actually has this property?

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven when my reputation is at 16,000 I'll change my name and profile picture.... do you know what it'll be

Comment: @Squirtle, alas, I do not....my Pokemon fandom is lacking....  my son could probably answer that.....

Comment: @DavidPrifti I want you to try to prove associativity...  It's not difficult.  You want to prove that $(\frac{k}{n} * \frac{l}{n})*\frac{p}{n} = \frac{k}{n} * (\frac{l}{n})*\frac{p}{n} $.  Just try doing it!  You ARE allowed to assume that $+$ is associative!  In fact, $*$ is commutative because $+$ is.  Just think about it!

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven It'll be Wartortle

Comment: Charazard does applied mathematics

Comment: I just looked up Squirtle, and it said level 16 was Wartortle!  Argh you beat me....